# Google Maps API v3 markers and circles suddenly stopped displaying

Tags: javascript, google-maps

My map was working perfectly; plotting markers with radius circles around them with infoWindows displaying on click. Then suddenly nothing.

- I went through the git history and no changes have been made to the code.
- It neither works locally nor deployed to a public domain.
- There are no JS errors.
- The addresses are being Geocoded correctly.
- The map itself renders.
- I am way below the rate limit.
- I checked the Google Maps API changelog and don't see anything pertinent.

Someone please find what I'm not seeing!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <style>
            #map_canvas {
                width:1000px;
                height:700px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>
        <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        <script>

            var addresses = ["117 Balsam Avenue,Hamilton,Ontario,Canada,L8M 3B4", "47 East Avenue,Hamilton,Ontario,Canada,L8L 5H4"];
            var map;
            var infoWindow;

            function encodeAddresses(addresses, callback) {
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                for (var i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
                    geocoder.geocode({
                        'address' : addresses[i]
                    }, function (results, status) {
                        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            var lat = results[0].geometry.location.Qa;
                            var long = results[0].geometry.location.Pa;
                            var address = results[0].formatted_address;
                            addCircleToMap(lat, long, address);
                            addMarkerToMap(lat, long, address);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            function addCircleToMap(lat, long, address) {
                var options = {
                    strokeColor : "#4EA429",
                    strokeOpacity : 0.8,
                    strokeWeight : 1,
                    fillColor : "#4EA429",
                    fillOpacity : 0.35,
                    map : map,
                    center : new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
                    radius : 1000,
                    address : address
                };
                var propertyRadius = new google.maps.Circle(options);
                google.maps.event.addListener(propertyRadius, 'click', showInfo);
            }

            function showInfo(e) {
                infoWindow.setContent(this.address + "<br />(1000m/3280ft radius)");
                infoWindow.setPosition(e.latLng);
                infoWindow.open(map);
            }

            function addMarkerToMap(lat, long, address) {
                new google.maps.Marker({
                    title : address,
                    map : map,
                    position : new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long)
                });
            }

            function renderMap() {
                var mapContainer = document.getElementById("map_canvas");
                var mapOptions = {
                        zoom : 9,
                        center : new google.maps.LatLng(43.645004, -79.380707),
                        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };
                adjustMapContainerHeight(mapContainer);
                map = new google.maps.Map(mapContainer, mapOptions);
                infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            }

            function adjustMapContainerHeight(element) {
                element.style.height = (document.height - 90) + "px";
            }

            function getCurrentPosition(defaultLatitude, defaultLongitude, callback) {  
                var currentPosition = {};
                    currentPosition.latitude = defaultLatitude;
                    currentPosition.longitude = defaultLongitude;
                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                        function (position) {
                        currentPosition.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                        currentPosition.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                    },
                        function (error) {});
                }
                callback(currentPosition);
            }

            getCurrentPosition(43.645004, -79.380707, renderMap);
            encodeAddresses(addresses, addCircleToMap);

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once try to change the following lines in  `encodeAddresses()` function.Its working fine in my machine with the changes:

```
var lat = results[0].geometry.location.Pa;    
 var long = results[0].geometry.location.Qa;
```

You are using `Pa` as `long` and `Qa` as `lat` which is not google supported one.So change the two lines and check.

Hope this helps you :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are using undocumented fields that change with each release of the API.

Use the `lat()` and `lng()` methods on the `LatLng` object.

See the [reference documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLng).